# Testing react hook that is refreshing a token based on timeout

Tags: react-hooks

```
export const useRefreshingToken = ({ ixId, learnerId, registrationId }: UseRefreshingTokenProps) => {

     const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState<number | null>(null);

    const { error, loading, reload, result } = useFetchData(gqlSdk.getToken, {
        itemId,
        userId,
        registrationId,
    });

    // Effect to refresh token ${tokenRefreshOffsetSeconds} before it expires
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!result?.token) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is already a scheduled reload dont need to set it again
        if (timeoutId || loading) {
            return;
        }

        const id = window.setTimeout(() => {
            reload();
            setTimeoutId(null);
            // Multiply by 1000 to go from seconds to milliseconds
        }, getRefreshTimeInMilliseconds(result.token.lifetimeSeconds));
        setTimeoutId(id);
    }, [reload, result, timeoutId, loading]);

    return {
        authToken: result?.token.tokenValue,
        loading: loading,
        error: error,
    };
```

I wrote this hook that updates the value of my authtoken whenever it is about to expire. I wondering how can i test the refresh logic here.

I can test using react-hook-testing library for the first render of this hook.

```
    it('Fetches a token from the gql api', async () => {
        mockedSdk.getToken.mockResolvedValueOnce({
            token: { lifetimeSeconds: 10, tokenValue: 'some-token' },
        });

        const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() =>
            useRefreshingToken({ id: 'ix1', userId: 'learner1', registrationId: 'registration1' }),
        );

        await waitForNextUpdate();

        expect(result.current.authToken).toEqual('some-token');
    });
```

I tried adding a piece of code await sleep(10) to sleep for 10 seconds then check the result value of the hook. However this does not seem to work. Or rather the state update happens but I can errors about how I am performing state updates outside of act().

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I can do

```
jest.useFakeTimers()
await act(async () => {
            jest.runAllTimers();
            await waitForNextUpdate();
        })
```

To fake a timer and execute it.